# Python: Problem with if statement

Tags: python

I have problem with a if statement code below:

```
do_blast(x):
    test_empty = open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/job_ID/%s.blast' % (z), 'r')
        if test_empty.read() == '':
            test_empty.close()
            return 'FAIL_NO_RESULTS'
        else:
            do_something

def return_blast(job_ID):
     if job_ID == 'FAIL_NO_RESULTS':
        return '<p>Sorry no results :( boooo</p>'
    else:
        return open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/job_ID/job_ID_%s.fasta' % (job_ID), 'r').read()
```

For some reason the code tries to assign "job_ID" to the fasta file in return_blast even though it should have returned "sorry no results". I also understand the file names and extensions are different i have my reasons for doing this.

The code works perfectly when the test_empty file is not empty.

Comment: How, exactly, are those two functions connected?

Comment: @Tim, I changed the indentation because it was misleading (and indentation is everything in python)

Comment: @Tim, the indentation in the code you posted was all wrong, so it's impossible to understand your problem.  Please check it and edit your Q (hint: don't use tabs -- indent with four spaces per level only).  Not sure @Brendan correctly read your mind in his indentation edit, since your problem might easily be connected to wrong indents (depending, as @Greg rightly asks, on how the two seemingly isolated functions actually "connect").

Comment: I didn't even notice the indentation in the second function. I would fix it too but it might be the cause of your error.. I reverted my previous edit just in case.

Comment: do_blast returns a integer (job_ID) if the file is not empty which is then retrieved from a URL by form.getfirst and passed through to return_blast

Comment: @Tim: I suspect your problem lies not in the code you posted here, but in the code between these two functions. It's impossible for us to tell why `job_ID` is not what you expect it to be with only the information you have supplied.

Comment: where is do_blast called? where is return_blast called?

Comment: So are you saying that if the blast file is empty, then return_blast will try to open a file named "/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/job_ID/job_ID_FAIL_NO_RESULTS.fasta" ? (As ars noted in a recent answer, it'd help all of us to know what the exact input to return_blast is.)


BTW, are you aware that you declare do_blast() with a parameter (x), but you format the blast filename with (z) (which is otherwise unassigned in the code you supplied)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but your code isn't indented correctly (and that matters in Python). I believe this is what you were wanting:

```
do_blast(x):
    test_empty = open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/job_ID/%s.blast' % (z), 'r')
    if test_empty.read() == '':
        test_empty.close()
        return 'FAIL_NO_RESULTS'
    else:
        do_something

def return_blast(job_ID):
    if job_ID == 'FAIL_NO_RESULTS':
        return '<p>Sorry no results :( boooo</p>'
    else:
        return open('/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/db/job_ID/job_ID_%s.fasta' % (job_ID), 'r').read()
```

I don't think your code would have even run though..

Comment: The code is indented correctly if my file. It runs when the file is not empty but fails to catch when the file is.

Comment: @Tim, please fix it in the question too so we know how your code actually looks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some simple printf style debugging will help:

```
def return_blast(job_ID):
    print 'job_ID: ', job_ID
    # ...
```

Then you can at least see what "job_ID" your function receives.  This is crucial for trying to figure out why your `if` statement fails.